# Hume and Strawson on Libertarianism and Determinism

Tags: determinism, hume, libertarianism-free-will

a) What is the traditional dispute between libertarianism and determinism, and how does Hume reconcile the two?

b) What is Strawson’s claim to be an improvement on Hume?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. We help with HW questions and essay prompts only if the poster presents their own reasoning and explains what the difficulty is.

Comment: You might want to split this into two questions and provide more detail on each, perhaps a reference to focus the question.  If your question does get closed, don't worry. I hope to read more questions and answers from you.